# python3 telnet connection read_all doesnt work

Tags: python-3.x, telnet

Can someone help me with this code?
I just can't figure out why it is not working. On console typing the command `cat /var/log/messages* |head -10` returns the 10 lines I want to see - here I always get '' returned!

```
import telnetlib
import time
def GetLogs(name, path):
    tempStr=''
    HOST = name
    user = "root"
    password = "asdf"
    tn = telnetlib.Telnet(HOST)
    tn.read_until(b"login: ")
    tn.write(user.encode('ascii') + b"\n")
    tn.read_until(b'Password: ')
    time.sleep(1)
    tn.write(password.encode('ascii') + b"\n")
    time.sleep(2)
    PATH_TO_LOG = "cat " + path + "\n"
    tn.write(PATH_TO_LOG.encode('ascii') + b"\n")
    tn.write(b"exit\n")
    tempStr=tn.read_all().decode('ascii')
    return tempStr.replace("\n", "<br>")

print(GetLogs("tb2-dm2", "/var/log/messages* |head -10"))
```

Sadly the given answers in other topics didn't help, as it was always the same problem - no connection close - but I did this here

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this code:

```
import telnetlib
import time
import getpass
import sys

COMMAND = sys.argv[1].encode('utf-8')
USER = input('Username: ').encode('utf-8')
PASSWORD = getpass.getpass().encode('utf-8')
ENABLE_PASS = getpass.getpass(prompt='Enter enable password: ').encode('utf-8')

IP = ""
print('Connection to device {}'.format(IP))
with telnetlib.Telnet(IP) as t:

    t.read_until(b'Username:')
    t.write(USER + b'\n')

    t.read_until(b'Password:')
    t.write(PASSWORD + b'\n')
    t.write(b'enable\n')

    t.read_until(b'Password:')
    t.write(ENABLE_PASS + b'\n')
    t.write(b'terminal length 0\n')
    t.write(COMMAND + b'\n')

    time.sleep(5)

    output = t.read_very_eager().decode('utf-8')
    print(output)
```

It work for me